# Bokeh plot: output file is appending instead of overwritting

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, data-visualization, bokeh

The code bellow was working fine, but ultimately it started to append multiple plots in the same HTML file each time the code is executed. That's a odd behavior, according to the Bokeh documentation, the function `output_file()` should overwrite the HTML file, instead of append it.

How can I prevent the output file to append multiple plots each time the script is executed?

My code: [an assembly function, part of a bigger project]

```
from bokeh.models import (HoverTool,
                          ColumnDataSource,
                          Title,
                          DatetimeTickFormatter)
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure


def assembly_chart(df, complements):
    """function to assembly the chart"""

    output_file("movigrama_chart.html")

    source = ColumnDataSource(df)

    p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime',
               x_axis_label='days of moviment',
               y_axis_label='unities movimented',
               plot_width=1230,
               plot_height=500,
               active_scroll='wheel_zoom')

    p.vbar(x='DT',
           bottom=0,
           top='STOCK',
           width=pd.Timedelta(days=1),
           fill_alpha=0.4,
           color='#99d8c9',
           source=source)

    p.vbar(x='DT',
           bottom=0,
           top='SOMA_SAI',
           width=pd.Timedelta(days=1),
           fill_alpha=0.8,
           color='crimson',
           source=source)

    p.vbar(x='DT',
           bottom=0,
           top='SOMA_ENTRA',
           width=pd.Timedelta(days=1),
           fill_alpha=0.8,
           color='seagreen',
           source=source)

    p.add_layout(Title(text=complements['warehouse'],
                       text_font='helvetica',
                       text_font_size='10pt',
                       text_color='orangered',
                       text_alpha=0.5,
                       align='center',
                       text_font_style="italic"), 'above')
    p.add_layout(Title(text=complements['product'],
                       text_font='helvetica',
                       text_font_size='10pt',
                       text_color='orangered',
                       text_alpha=0.5,
                       align='center',
                       text_font_style="italic"), 'above')
    p.add_layout(Title(text='Movigrama Endicon',
                       text_font='helvetica',
                       text_font_size='16pt',
                       text_color='orangered',
                       text_alpha=0.9,
                       align='center',
                       text_font_style="bold"), 'above')

    p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
    p.y_range.range_padding = 0.1

    p.outline_line_width = 4
    p.outline_line_alpha = 0.1
    p.outline_line_color = 'orangered'

    p.axis.major_label_text_color = 'gray'
    p.axis.major_label_text_font_style = 'bold'

    p.axis.axis_label_text_color = 'gray'
    p.axis.axis_label_text_font_style = 'bold'

    p.axis.major_tick_out = 10
    p.axis.minor_tick_in = -3
    p.axis.minor_tick_out = 6
    p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = 'gray'

    p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(
                days=['%d/%m'],
                months=['%m/%Y'],
                years=['%Y'])

    # iniciate hover object
    hover = HoverTool()
    hover.mode = 'vline'  # activate hover by vertical line
    hover.tooltips = [("IN", "@SOMA_ENTRA"),
                      ("OUT", "@SOMA_SAI"),
                      ("STOCK", "@STOCK"),
                      ("DT", "@DT{%d/%m/%Y}")]
    # use 'datetime' formatter for 'DT' field
    hover.formatters = {"DT": 'datetime'}
    p.add_tools(hover)

    show(p)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `output_file()` function was supposed to take care of it, overwriting the HTML file each time it is executed. At least that is what is written in the documentation of `bokeh.io` [[link]](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html).

> Warning
>
> This output file will be overwritten on every save, e.g., each time
>   show() or save() is invoked.

So, if you are facing this problem the solution is easy. You just have to import the `reset_output` from bokeh.io and than invoke it just after you call the `output_file` function.

```
from bokeh.io import reset_output

[...code here...]

output_file("filename.html")
reset_output()

[...more code here...]
```

Comment: This fixes the issue, indeed. I saw the same behavior just recently, it is strange as before that it was working without reset_output (like it should). I wonder if this issue is specific to a bokeh version? I saw this with bokeh 0.13.0